# Some Rebux Puzzles

Tags: visual, rebus

Here are some Rebux Puzzles I got :-

[image: Rebux Puzzles]

How many could you solve ? :-)

Comment: Part of this seems to be from [here](http://www.thinkablepuzzles.com/bamboozables/bamboozable40.shtml)

Comment: I've deleted my partial answer. Found the same on Pinterest: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/563020390910980285/ .I'm voting to close

Answer (score 2):

English is not my first language, so puzzles like these are often hard, but here's a stab at most of them

1:

> Back pain

4:

> Head over heals in love

5:

> Count down(?)

6:

> Apple turnover

7:

> Merry go round

8:

> Four square (a ball game)

9:

> Three little pigs

Comment: I think 5 is rot13(pbhag va n yvar) or something like that

Comment: I think 1 is rot13(ybjre onpx cnva), since the position seems relevant. 3 could be rot13(gur fubeg raq bs gur fgvpx). Maybe rot13(funxvat nyy bire) for 2?